# View-based table view with NSColorWell

Tags: cocoa

I have a an NSMutableArray set up with objects that have a color, a bool value, and a name.  I would like to have the array displayed in a table view with a color well depicting the object's color value, a check box for its bool value and then the name in the third column.  I haven't had trouble setting up a table view with just a check box and name, however I am running in to some issues trying to get a color well to show up in the table.

I'm fairly certain I need to use a view-based table view instead of cell based table view, and that is where I am running into trouble.  Am I supposed to use bindings to set up the table?  If so how might I do that?

If not, what would be the correct way to set up a view-based table view?
I've tried using

`- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView`

and

`- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`

However this doesn't seem to work.  I've looked into using an NSArrayController, but I don't think that's what I need to implement this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use bindings -- that's the way I usually do it. Apple has a section in it's table view programming guide called. "Populating View-Based Table Views using Cocoa Bindings". You should read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that worked.

I used a custom cell called LVColorWellCell (http://ringce.com/code/Cocoa/lvcolorwellcell) to implement a color well cell in a cell-based table view and it works great!